# fullScreenCover is presenting a blank sheet, despite no errors being thrown and multiple fixes being tried

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I am trying to develop my first full stack application using SwiftUI, and I am attempting to navigate between a view called "LoginView" that handles user login, to a view called DataInputView, that handles the input of a new users Data. Unfortunately, the sheet being presented is completely blank. I am new to swift so please excuse poor coding practices. Here are the relevant pieces of Code. Ignore all comments please as they are meant for potential future co-developers, also, some functionality is not yet complete.

```
//
//  UserMetaDataViewModel.swift


import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage


@MainActor
class UserMetaDataViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var userMetaData: UserMetaData
    
    init(userMetaData: UserMetaData = UserMetaData(id: "", email: "", nameFirst: "", nameLast: "", handle: "", gender: Gender.other, age: 0, bio: "", dataInputComplete: false)) {
        self.userMetaData = userMetaData
    } //Creates new userMetaData object with no params. This is how it will be done every time a new user is created. calling UserMetaDataViewModel() will create a new UserMetaData object with empty fields such that the program and database will be able to recognize "default data" and handle it accordingly. This data will then be updated with the saveUserData field, which takes an instance of UserMetaData.
    
    
    //TODO: updateField function which takes a metaData field as a parameter and updates the specific field in the metadata
    
    
    func saveUserData(userMetaData: UserMetaData) async -> String? {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        if let id = userMetaData.id {
            do {
                try await db.collection("userMetaData").document(id).setData(userMetaData.dictionary)
                print("Success in saving data for user \(userMetaData.nameFirst)")
                return nil // Indicate success with nil
            } catch {
                print("Error could not update data in 'userMetaData'")
                return error.localizedDescription // Return error message on failure
            }
        } else {
            print("Error could not create a new instance of UserMetaData: UID is nil")
            return "User ID is nil" // Return error message
        }
    }

    func loadUserData() async -> Bool {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return false }

        do {
            let document = try await db.collection("userMetaData").document(userID).getDocument()
            print("Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
            
            if document.exists {
                do {
                    let loadedUserData = try document.data(as: UserMetaData.self)
                    self.userMetaData = loadedUserData
                    return true
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding user data: \(error)")
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                print("Document not found")
                return false
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error loading user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }


    
    func saveProfilePic(userMetaData: UserMetaData, image: UIImage) async -> Bool {
        guard let userEmail = userMetaData.email else {
            print("error finding ID of userMetaData")
            return false
        }
        let photoName = UUID().uuidString
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child("\(userEmail)/\(photoName).jpeg")
        
        guard let resizedImage = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else {
            print("Error, could not resize image")
            return false
        }
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        
        var imageURLString = ""
        do {
            let _ = try await storageRef.putDataAsync(resizedImage, metadata: metadata)
            do {
                let imageURL = try await storageRef.downloadURL()
                imageURLString = "\(imageURL)"
            } catch {
                print("Error: could not get ImageUrl after saving profile URL")
            }
            print("profile image saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error uploading image to firebase storage")
            return false
        }
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let collectionString = "email/\(userEmail)/profilePic"
        
       /* do {
            userMetaData.profilePictureURL = imageURLString
            try await db.collection(collectionString).document(photoName).set
        } catch {
        
        } */
        return true
    }
}
//
//  DataInputView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct DataInputView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userMetaDataVM: UserMetaDataViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Enter Information")) {
                TextField("First", text: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.nameFirst)
                TextField("First", text: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.nameLast)
                TextField("Handle", text: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.handle)
                Picker("Gender", selection: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.gender) {
                    ForEach(Gender.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                TextField("Age", value: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.age, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                TextField("Bio", text: $userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.bio)
            }

            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    if let email = userMetaDataVM.userMetaData.email {
                        _ = await userMetaDataVM.saveUserData(userMetaData: userMetaDataVM.userMetaData)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Continue")
            }
        }
    }
}



struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataInputView(userMetaDataVM: UserMetaDataViewModel(userMetaData: UserMetaData(id: "", email: "", nameFirst: "", nameLast: "", handle: "", gender: Gender(rawValue: "") ?? Gender.male, age: 10, bio: "", profilePictureURL: "", dataInputComplete: false)))
    }
}
//
//  UserMetaDataViewModel.swift


import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage


@MainActor
class UserMetaDataViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var userMetaData: UserMetaData
    
    init(userMetaData: UserMetaData = UserMetaData(id: "", email: "", nameFirst: "", nameLast: "", handle: "", gender: Gender.other, age: 0, bio: "", dataInputComplete: false)) {
        self.userMetaData = userMetaData
    } //Creates new userMetaData object with no params. This is how it will be done every time a new user is created. calling UserMetaDataViewModel() will create a new UserMetaData object with empty fields such that the program and database will be able to recognize "default data" and handle it accordingly. This data will then be updated with the saveUserData field, which takes an instance of UserMetaData.
    
    
    //TODO: updateField function which takes a metaData field as a parameter and updates the specific field in the metadata
    
    
    func saveUserData(userMetaData: UserMetaData) async -> String? {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        if let id = userMetaData.id {
            do {
                try await db.collection("userMetaData").document(id).setData(userMetaData.dictionary)
                print("Success in saving data for user \(userMetaData.nameFirst)")
                return nil // Indicate success with nil
            } catch {
                print("Error could not update data in 'userMetaData'")
                return error.localizedDescription // Return error message on failure
            }
        } else {
            print("Error could not create a new instance of UserMetaData: UID is nil")
            return "User ID is nil" // Return error message
        }
    }

    func loadUserData() async -> Bool {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return false }

        do {
            let document = try await db.collection("userMetaData").document(userID).getDocument()
            print("Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
            
            if document.exists {
                do {
                    let loadedUserData = try document.data(as: UserMetaData.self)
                    self.userMetaData = loadedUserData
                    return true
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding user data: \(error)")
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                print("Document not found")
                return false
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error loading user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return false
        }
    }


    
    func saveProfilePic(userMetaData: UserMetaData, image: UIImage) async -> Bool {
        guard let userEmail = userMetaData.email else {
            print("error finding ID of userMetaData")
            return false
        }
        let photoName = UUID().uuidString
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child("\(userEmail)/\(photoName).jpeg")
        
        guard let resizedImage = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else {
            print("Error, could not resize image")
            return false
        }
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        
        var imageURLString = ""
        do {
            let _ = try await storageRef.putDataAsync(resizedImage, metadata: metadata)
            do {
                let imageURL = try await storageRef.downloadURL()
                imageURLString = "\(imageURL)"
            } catch {
                print("Error: could not get ImageUrl after saving profile URL")
            }
            print("profile image saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error uploading image to firebase storage")
            return false
        }
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let collectionString = "email/\(userEmail)/profilePic"
        
       /* do {
            userMetaData.profilePictureURL = imageURLString
            try await db.collection(collectionString).document(photoName).set
        } catch {
        
        } */
        return true
    }
}
```

I have tried ensuring that there are no concurrency issues, ensured that data is being saved to firebase properly, and that authentication works properly. I seriously cannot tell you as to why I cannot get the proper sheet to appear.

Comment: `... fullScreenCover is presenting a blank sheet, ...` where is the `fullScreenCover` code? where do you call it and how do you present it?
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why do you show the code for `UserMetaDataViewModel` twice?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of bugs are usually occur when attempting to use view model objects instead of learning the `View` struct. So first of all I would recommend removing:

```
@MainActor
class UserMetaDataViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
```

to

```
struct UserController {
```

This should not be `@MainActor` so its async funcs can run on background threads. And since you are not using Combine you can change it to a struct and remove the `ObservableObject` conformance. Finally, in SwiftUI we use the `.task(id:)` modifier instead of `Task { }`.

So you should end up with something like this:

```
Button("Save") {
    metadataToSave = Metadata(email, firstName, lastName) // from text field states.
}
.disabled(metadataToSave != nil)
.task(id: metadataToSave) {
    if metadataToSave == nil {
        return
    }
    do {
        try await userController.saveUserData(userMetaData: metadataToSave)
    }
    catch {
        errorMessage = "Failed"
    }
    metadataToSave = nil
}
```